# How to send back information from the detail view to master view

Tags: uitableview

I have a master view with a tableview, then I go to the detail and modify it. what is the best practice to get the modify value, store it to my NSArray and update my tableview ?

I have made a delegate method in my detail view to call back my master view after modification, is it good? If you have a simple example with modify detail view.